# Updating multiple rows in MySQL table with a button click

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been at this for hours and nothing is working, so your help is greatly appreciated.

I have a table that is dynamically filled with invoices that need a supervisor's approval.  I'm trying to create the ability for a supervisor to click an 'Approve' all button and have the MySQL table column update with the supervisor's ID for each of the invoices (which have their own unique Job ID in the MySQL table).

I've tried things such as: a while loop that places each job ID in an array, a loop that inserts each ID and passes it to another page using 'get', along with a number of other overly complex solutions.

It seems like there would be a simple way to do this that I'm missing.

Because nothing is working, I don't have a lot of code to show, but here is the query that will update the table.  This is what I'm using to approve a single invoice, what I need is the ability to approve all the invoices that show on the page.

UPDATE jobs
SET job_approverid2='".$approverid."'
WHERE job_id = '".$jobid."'

Comment: Explanation is bit confusing. Can you tell where is you approve button, what do you show to approver?

Comment: Can you show the code here? That will help us understand the issue. The explanation of what you have done is not clear.

Comment: The approve button is below the table where I'm displaying the invoices.  There really isn't any code to show because nothing has even come close to working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple rows update, I'm asuming you have multiple job_ids

```
$jobid = implode(',' ,$_POST['jobid']); // just example

UPDATE jobs SET job_approverid2='".$approverid."' WHERE job_id IN (".$jobid.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple `UPDATE` with a condition should do it:

```
UPDATE invoices SET approved = 1 WHERE .. condition ..
```

the **..condition..** determines what invoices get approval, like:

```
UPDATE invoices SET approved = 1 WHERE approved = 0
```

In order to approve ALL the invoices that are not approved. Of course, the `WHERE` clause can be more complex, for example, to update all the invoices with supervisor having `id = 23` :

```
UPDATE invoices SET approved = 1 WHERE approved = 0 AND supervisor_id = 23
```

So, at application level, you only have to create a page that executes the above query, it might have a url like:

```
http://example.com/invoices/approve_all.php?supervisor=23
```

Comment: I've already programmed the ability for supervisors to approve a single ticket, where it updates the approved column to the supervisor's ID.  However how can I get the process to happen automatically for a ever changing number of invoices and invoice IDs - with one click from the user?

Comment: It all stays in the above `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement. I guess you are having a clause like `WHERE invoice_id = X`, take that out. If you don't show us the code that is doing the update, we can only continue guessing how it looks and what puzzles you, without really helping.

Comment: I just edited the question to include the update query I'm running.

Comment: try with: `UPDATE jobs SET job_approverid2='".$approverid."' ` this will set `job_approverid2` to `$approverid` on ALL your rows

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
"UPDATE jobs SET job_approverid2='".$approverid."' WHERE job_id = '".$jobid."' and job_approverid2!='".$approverid"'"
```

or else you can do like this

get all the job Id as an array( lets say **$jobId[]**) where **job_approverid2!=$approverid**

Then

```
foreach($jobId[] as $job_id) {
 "UPDATE jobs SET job_approverid2='".$approverid."' WHERE job_id = '".$job_id."'"
}
```